# \left and \right brackets way too huge!

Tags: equations, brackets

I have an Equation written with the following code:

```
\vec{B}(\vec{m},\vec{r}) \sim \left(\frac{3\left[\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
m
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\right] \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
m
\end{pmatrix}}{r^3}\right)
```

But it looks like this:
[image]

how can I make the brackets smaller?

Comment: Why not use `\frac{1}{r^3}` on the left of the matrices?

Comment: good point, thx, but out of curiosity, how could I have done that?

Comment: Also, why do you need the outer parenthesis?

Comment: because there will be additional factors, its not the whole thing but I guess I could also leave them

Comment: @Kathiieee The fences are alway vertically centered with respect to the fraction line.

Comment: to use the suggestion by @Sigur, restructure your right-hand-side as `\frac{1}{r^3} \left(`<all the matrices>`\right)` -- that will center the matrices vertically around the math axis.

Comment: @Kathiieee: Shouldn't the first matrix be transposed?

Comment: @Bernard I think it is meant to indicate a dot product of vectors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason you are getting the extra space is the following:  fractions are placed so that the fraction line lies on the "math axis", which is a little above the baseline, at about the height of a minus sign, and the stretchy delimiters produced by `\left...\right` are centered on the math axis as well, so they extend above and below the math axis by the same amount.  That will be the maximum of the extent above the math axis and the extent below it of the enclosed material.  In your case, the material above the axis is much larger, so the delimiters extend that far below as well.

One way to get around this is to use `\vcenter` to recenter the equation vertically so that the fraction line is not on the math axis.  You need to use `\vcenter{\hbox{$\displaystyle...$}}` inside the `\left...\right`.  For example

```
\vec{B}(\vec{m},\vec{r}) \sim
\left(\vcenter{\hbox{$\displaystyle
\frac{3\left[\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\m\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\right]
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\m\end{pmatrix}}{r^3}
$}}\right)
```

produces

[image: Use of \vcenter]

Note, however, that some will find this distasteful since the fraction is not properly centered, so the other answers may be preferable.

Comment: Using `gathered`, instead of explicitly doing `\vcenter`, hides the complicatins.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a possible solution that starts with @Sigur 's comment and suggests a strategy that may make the semantics easier for your reader. It's too long for a comment. If I read your expression correctly the first multiplication dot is an inner product while the second is a scalar times a vector.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Let
\begin{equation*}
\alpha = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
m
\end{pmatrix}\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
= m \cos(\theta) .
\end{equation*}
%
Then
\begin{align}
\vec{B}(\vec{m},\vec{r}) 
& \sim 
\frac{1}{r^3}
\left(
3 \alpha \begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
m
\end{pmatrix}
\right) \\
& = \text{finish simplifying \ldots}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the problem of fraction not properly centered with \vcenter, with a commend like this:

```
\newcommand{\centerp}[2]{\lower #1pt\hbox{$\ds\left(\vcenter{\hbox{$\ds #2$}}\right)$}}
```

Use:

```
$$
\vec{B}(\vec{m},\vec{r}) \sim
\centrap{-14}{\frac{3\left[\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\m\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\right]
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\m\end{pmatrix}}{r^3}
}
$$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code uses macros named `\ds` and `\centrap`. How or where are they defined?

Comment: Please also consider streamlining your code by replacing `\lower -14pt` with `\raise 14pt`.

Answer (score 0):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
X \sim {\sbox0{$\displaystyle
             \left(\begin{gathered}
             \frac{3\left[\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}\right]
                     - \begin{pmatrix}d\\e\\f\end{pmatrix}}
                  {r^3}
                   \end{gathered}
             \right)
               $}\raise.5\ht0\box0}
  \sim \frac{Y}{r^3} \sim\frac {Z}{r}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: equation with large parenthesis]

Part of this uses [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220370/left-and-right-brackets-way-too-huge#comment518017_220445) to 2015 answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220445/293669.

Comment: This method needs adjustment if the denominator has some significant height; one would probably then have to configure a macro `\ParenFrac` which would measure vertical extent of numerator and denominator first.  Or, simply manually tune the `\raise` with a `\dimexpr0.5\ht0 + <whatever>`.